# Possible?? Pull Plugin Property Data to a Theme's Custom Post Type

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

I bought a real estate theme and want to use the property listing data that I get from a paid plugin.

The plugin listing data is clean, and stored in the WP database.

The theme uses custom post types so I'm trying to bridge my plugin data to the theme.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds possible for sure! is that your only question? For more specifics we'd need more to go on... :)

Comment: Does the plugin also use a custom post type?

Comment: @Michelle yes that's all that I need :P -- anything specifically you need to know?

Comment: @JHoffmann yes, it seems the plugin (soldpress) does use a custom post type.

Comment: If you're using Soldpress, is there a reason you don't want to use their templates / display options? it seems like that would be easier than recreating the display by custom-coding your theme.

Comment: @Michelle  having used their display options, it came with a ton of limitations. The new theme would allow for scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting this in as an "answer" just to give you pointers on where to start. Once you have specific questions concerning code you'll probably want to ask new questions.

First, I'd create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). (Look on Google, there are tons of examples/tutorials on how to do that.)

In your child theme, create [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types) for the relevant custom post type. (I'd copy the archive.php and single.php files from your parent theme into your child theme, then edit the filenames.) Typically these would be named archive-CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME.php and single-CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME.php.

On those two template files you should be able to reference/display the custom fields created by the plugin using [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

If all works as expected, voila and hooray! But there may be challenges depending on how the plugin is written and how it stores the information, so be sure to check back with the plugin creator and us before it drives you crazy. :)